# query result of Mysql statement

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
 Id    Name    ParentName
 100   Alain    400
 200   Maria    400
 300   Robert   500
 400   Fred     0
 500   Steve    0
```

What I want to extract from this table is the following :

```
Name    ParentName
Alain   Fred
Maria   Fred
Robert  Steve
```

I have tried the following statement but did not get the needed result :

```
SELECT Name,ParentName
FROM tblFam
WHERE ParentName
IN ( SELECT Id FROM tblFam)
```

Any idea how to get it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the same table something as

```
select
t1.name,
t2.name as parentname
from table_name t1
left join table_name t2 on t1.ParentName = t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inner join:

```
SELECT child.Name, parent.Name FROM tblFam child
INNER JOIN tblFam parent ON parent.Id = child.ParentName
```

A small observation though: it's better to rename `ParentName` to `ParentId`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Name FROM tblFam WHERE id = ParentName) AS ParentName 
FROM tblFam;
```